# React.js, timeout - how to hide a div after a few seconds

Tags: reactjs, forms, timeout

I am making a form using react.js. I am attempting to make a div appear and then disappear after the form has been submitted. How can I correctly do this?

My code currently just take me to a blank page when the form has been submitted.

Updated on request

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      messageConfirm: ''
    }

    this.handleInput1 = this.handleInput1.bind(this);
    this.handleInput2 = this.handleInput2.bind(this);
    this.handleInput3 = this.handleInput3.bind(this);
    this.sendEmail = this.sendEmail.bind(this)
    this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this)
  }

  resetForm() {
   //reset form
  }

  validateForm() {
    //validate form method
  }

  sendEmail(e) {
  //send email method
  }

  confirmEmailMessage(){
    this.setState({messageConfirm: "Thanks for your message"})
  }

  setTimeOut(){
    this.setState({messageConfirm: ""}, 5000)
  }
  
  
  submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const isValid = this.validateForm();
    if (isValid) {
      // this.sendEmail(e)
      this.confirmEmailMessage()
      this.setTimeOut()
      e.target.reset()
      this.resetForm()
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="contact-form container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center bd-highlight" id="contact-form">
          <form onSubmit={this.submitForm} data-testid="form">
            //form code
          </form>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your component code, with reproduction steps and any debugging details you've done. Try to limit SO questions to a single specific issue.

Comment: @DrewReese does this help?

Comment: Ah, no, but I actually misread your code originally and what it is trying to do. I can help resolve the updating message state issue, but would need to see more (likely all) of the component to see what or why it would render a blank page after form submission.

Comment: @DrewReese Ive just updated my question to display most of the component. Thanks for taking the time to look.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks a lot for your answer, worked like a charm.

Comment: Great, because I wasn't seeing a way the described behavior from your existing code snippet could happen and I was about to create a codesandbox to see if I could. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React's `this.setState`'s second argument is a callback function, not a static value. You probably meant to call `setTimeout` with a callback to update state. I also suggest changing the name of *your* function to something more meaningful, like `resetMessage` so it isn't as ambiguous. Then for completionist's sake you should save the timer ref and clear it when the component unmounts so you don't try to set state of an unmounted component.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    messageConfirm: '',
  };
  this.timerId = null;
}

resetMessage() {
  this.timerId = setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({ messageConfirm: "" });
     this.timerId = null;
  }, 5000);
}

submitForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const isValid = this.validateForm();

  if (isValid) {
    this.confirmEmailMessage();
    this.resetMessage();
    e.target.reset();
    this.resetForm();
  }
}

...

componentWillUnmount() {
  cleatTimeout(this.timerId);
}
```